# utf8 with Mysql-5.0.88, ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.2 and snow leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard

I'm just starting with the depot application in the Pragmatic Programmer's Rails book. When I try doing a rake db:create RAILS_ENV-'development' after creating a rails application, I get the following error:

Couldn't create database for {"encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"depot_development", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_general_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)

My my.cnf looks like this:

[mysqld]
character-set-filesystem=UTF8
character-set-server=UTF8
default-collation=UTF8_general_ci
default-character-set=UTF8

[client]
default-character-set=UTF8

[mysqldump]
default-character-set=UTF8

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue with snow leopard.

this was solved via:

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```